22.04 Laptop Monitor Randomly Freezes
I have a XPG Xenia-14 laptop that I have been using Ubuntu 22.04 for a while now on. My typical setup is 2 external monitors and my laptop monitor as a third running through VisionTek VT7100 docking station.
Recently my laptop screen will start to freeze but my external monitors can still be used. I can't drag anything to my laptop monitor either. The only fix so far is to hard reset it by holding the power button down or pressing the power the button to get the confirmation box to appear to restart or shutdown which seems to unfreeze the monitor. Nothing will happen to indicate that its frozen but suddenly it just becomes unusable.
Some system details:
r00tk1t@r00tk1t-XENIA-14:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
r00tk1t@r00tk1t-XENIA-14:~
r00tk1t@r00tk1t-XENIA-14:~$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            23Gi       4.5Gi        13Gi       778Mi       4.8Gi        17Gi
Swap:          1.9Gi          0B       1.9Gi
r00tk1t@r00tk1t-XENIA-14:~$ df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                      2.4G  2.8M  2.4G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root  465G   33G  409G   8% /
tmpfs                       12G  104K   12G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
efivarfs                   192K  109K   79K  59% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/nvme0n1p2             1.7G  304M  1.3G  20% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1             511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                      2.4G  2.4M  2.4G   1% /run/user/1000
r00tk1t@r00tk1t-XENIA-14:~$ lscpu -e
CPU NODE SOCKET CORE L1d:L1i:L2:L3 ONLINE    MAXMHZ   MINMHZ      MHZ
  0    0      0    0 0:0:0:0          yes 4200.0000 400.0000 1009.650
  1    0      0    1 1:1:1:0          yes 4200.0000 400.0000 1300.000
  2    0      0    2 2:2:2:0          yes 4200.0000 400.0000  712.931
  3    0      0    3 3:3:3:0          yes 4200.0000 400.0000 1117.396
  4    0      0    0 0:0:0:0          yes 4200.0000 400.0000 1200.000
  5    0      0    1 1:1:1:0          yes 4200.0000 400.0000  400.000
  6    0      0    2 2:2:2:0          yes 4200.0000 400.0000  699.684
  7    0      0    3 3:3:3:0          yes 4200.0000 400.0000  987.078
r00tk1t@r00tk1t-XENIA-14:~

Troubleshooting:

reboot several times
run sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Cleared apt cache with sudo apt-get clean--dry-run
Free up some space and remove residual files with sudo apt-get autoremove and sudo apt-get autoclean

Any thoughts on what it could be or ways to fix it?
